# Laravel showed successful rolled back message but nothing was rolled back at all

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, migration

I first ran the `php artisan migrate` and I got error in between in one of the migration files. So I read and tried to rollback the last `batch of migrations` which were run.

So I ran command `php artisan migrate:rollback` and it gave me this output.

```
Rolling back: 2019_02_01_000132_create_user_comment_table
Rolled back:  2019_02_01_000132_create_user_comment_table (0.03 seconds)
Rolling back: 2019_02_01_000131_create_chat_table
Rolled back:  2019_02_01_000131_create_chat_table (0 seconds)
Rolling back: 2019_02_01_000130_create_chat_thread_table
Rolled back:  2019_02_01_000130_create_chat_thread_table (0 seconds)
Rolling back: 2019_02_01_000129_create_chat_template_table
Rolled back:  2019_02_01_000129_create_chat_template_table (0 seconds)
Rolling back: 2019_02_01_000128_update_logistics_park_address
Rolled back:  2019_02_01_000128_update_logistics_park_address (0 seconds)
Rolling back: 2019_02_01_000127_update_sponsored_listing_status
Rolled back:  2019_02_01_000127_update_sponsored_listing_status (0 seconds)
Rolling back: 2019_02_01_000126_update_logistics_park_cluster_id
Rolled back:  2019_02_01_000126_update_logistics_park_cluster_id (0 seconds)
Rolling back: 2019_02_01_000125_update_provider_company
Rolled back:  2019_02_01_000125_update_provider_company (0 seconds)
Rolling back: 2019_02_01_000124_update_category_code
Rolled back:  2019_02_01_000124_update_category_code (0 seconds)
Rolling back: 2019_02_01_000123_update_cluster_price
Rolled back:  2019_02_01_000123_update_cluster_price (0 seconds)
Rolling back: 2019_02_01_000122_create_contact_logistics_park_table
Rolled back:  2019_02_01_000122_create_contact_logistics_park_table (0 seconds)
Rolling back: 2019_02_01_000121_update_customer_job
Rolled back:  2019_02_01_000121_update_customer_job (0 seconds)
Rolling back: 2019_02_01_000120_update_contact_stockarea_project_duration
Rolled back:  2019_02_01_000120_update_contact_stockarea_project_duration (0 seconds)
Rolling back: 2019_02_01_000119_create_sponsored_listing_table
Rolled back:  2019_02_01_000119_create_sponsored_listing_table (0 seconds)
Rolling back: 2019_02_01_000118_update_user_validation
Rolled back:  2019_02_01_000118_update_user_validation (0 seconds)
Rolling back: 2019_02_01_000117_update_user_email
Rolled back:  2019_02_01_000117_update_user_email (0 seconds)
Rolling back: 2019_02_01_000116_update_warehouse_category_status
Rolled back:  2019_02_01_000116_update_warehouse_category_status (0 seconds)
Rolling back: 2019_02_01_000115_update_warehouse_category_root
Rolled back:  2019_02_01_000115_update_warehouse_category_root (0 seconds)
Rolling back: 2019_02_01_000114_update_logistic_park_cluster
Rolled back:  2019_02_01_000114_update_logistic_park_cluster (0 seconds)
Rolling back: 2019_02_01_000113_delete_logistic_park_cluster
Rolled back:  2019_02_01_000113_delete_logistic_park_cluster (0 seconds)
Rolling back: 2019_02_01_000112_create_acl_table
Rolled back:  2019_02_01_000112_create_acl_table (0 seconds)
Rolling back: 2019_02_01_000111_create_acl_action_table
Rolled back:  2019_02_01_000111_create_acl_action_table (0 seconds)
Rolling back: 2019_02_01_000110_create_acl_category_table
Rolled back:  2019_02_01_000110_create_acl_category_table (0 seconds)
Rolling back: 2019_02_01_000109_update_user_auth
Rolled back:  2019_02_01_000109_update_user_auth (0 seconds)
Rolling back: 2019_02_01_000108_create_username_or_email_on_hold_table
Rolled back:  2019_02_01_000108_create_username_or_email_on_hold_table (0 seconds)
Rolling back: 2019_02_01_000107_create_denied_access_table
Rolled back:  2019_02_01_000107_create_denied_access_table (0 seconds)
Rolling back: 2019_02_01_000106_create_login_error_table
Rolled back:  2019_02_01_000106_create_login_error_table (0 seconds)
Rolling back: 2019_02_01_000105_create_ips_on_hold_table
Rolled back:  2019_02_01_000105_create_ips_on_hold_table (0 seconds)
Rolling back: 2019_02_01_000104_create_auth_session_table
Rolled back:  2019_02_01_000104_create_auth_session_table (0 seconds)
Rolling back: 2019_02_01_000103_create_cl_session_table
Rolled back:  2019_02_01_000103_create_cl_session_table (0 seconds)
Rolling back: 2019_02_01_000102_update_company_website
Rolled back:  2019_02_01_000102_update_company_website (0 seconds)
Rolling back: 2019_02_01_000101_update_user_company
Rolled back:  2019_02_01_000101_update_user_company (0 seconds)
Rolling back: 2019_02_01_000100_update_warehouse_logistics
Rolled back:  2019_02_01_000100_update_warehouse_logistics (0 seconds)
Rolling back: 2019_02_01_000099_create_logistics_park_table
Rolled back:  2019_02_01_000099_create_logistics_park_table (0 seconds)
Rolling back: 2019_02_01_000098_create_customer_table
Rolled back:  2019_02_01_000098_create_customer_table (0 seconds)
Rolling back: 2019_02_01_000096_create_company_table
Rolled back:  2019_02_01_000096_create_company_table (0 seconds)
Rolling back: 2019_02_01_000095_create_warehouse_category_mapping_table
Rolled back:  2019_02_01_000095_create_warehouse_category_mapping_table (0 seconds)
Rolling back: 2019_02_01_000094_create_warehouse_category_table
Rolled back:  2019_02_01_000094_create_warehouse_category_table (0 seconds)
```

But when I went to see my database nothing was rolled back. NO tables were deleted. But entries from `migrations` table were deleted. Now this has lead into me a great trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `down()` method provided in each migration file **MUST NOT BE EMPTY**

> A migration class contains two methods: up and down. The up method is
>   used to add new tables, columns, or indexes to your database, while
>   the down method should reverse the operations performed by the up
>   method.

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations)